# Django error: no such table "boletin_registrado"

Tags: python, django, database, model, server

I have this error with a new app I'm developing that is an e-mail bulletin inside  my landing page.

I made my model (is only one table) named "registrado" inside models.py but when i run server it says that there is no table named "registrado" but... it actually is since I wrote it in models.py and dont know why I'm having this error

The code of models.py is this

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db  import models

class registrado(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    codigo_postal = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    actualizado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)   

    def __unicode__ (self):

        return self.email
```

Then I modify the settings.py file in INSTALLED APPS putting the name of the app at the end of the list

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'boletin',
]
```

and finally, register the app in admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import registrado

class Adminregistrado(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "nombre", "timestamp"]
    class Meta:
        model = registrado

admin.site.register(registrado, Adminregistrado)
```

Sorry for the long post and thank you for your help :/

Comment: the table name will have a prefix with the `app` name. so for your case, the full table name will be `boletin_registrado` not `registrado`, recommend you to use `manage.py makemigration` and `manage.py migrate` to sync the db.

Answer (score 1):

you can check as Follows:

> Go to Your project directory.
>
> After creating models
>
> 1. makemigrations
> 2. migrate

When you have done new migration files, you have to apply them to your database to make sure they work as expected:

```
cd /var/opt/boletin
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

#You can check table in database as follows:
python manage.py dbshell 
\dt
```

> Here You will get all Tables that having actual Database name.
>   Table Name generated using "application name and table name" in small case.

```
Application Name = "boletin"
Table Name = "registrado"

eg: Application Name + "_" + Table Name= "boletin_registrado”
```

In your application you can use as follows:

```
cd /var/opt/boletin
python manage.py shell 
from boletin.models import registrado or from boletin.models import *

registrado_obj = registrado.(numbre = numbre, email=email, codigo_postal=codigo_postal, timestamp=timestamp, actualizado=actualizado)
registrado_obj.save()
```